# writing a matrix in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a series of arrays of equal length, and want to make a matrix for each data point of these, and perform some sort of operation such a multiplying the matrices.

```
a=ones(1,10);
b=3*ones(1,10);
c=zeros(1,10);

for i=1:10
    A(i)=[a(i) a(i); 
          b(i) b(i)];
    B(i)=[c(i) c(i)];
    C(i)=B(i)*A(i);
end
```

Is this possible without using cells?

Comment: You can use a 3d-matrix to store A, use assignments like `A(:,:,i)=...`

Answer (score 2):

```
A = zeros(2,2,length(a));
B = zeros(length(a),:);
C = zeros(size(B));

for i=1:10
    A(:,:,i)=[a(i) a(i); 
              b(i) b(i)];
    B(i,:)=[c(i) c(i)];
    C(i,:)=B(i,:)*A(:,:,i);
end
```

Note you can make `A` and `B` without loops:

```
aa = permute(A, [3,2,1]);
bb = permute(B, [3,2,1]);
A = [aa,aa;bb,bb];

B = [c.', c.'];
```